# action when Value in a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a simple code for testing --- the action is a little bit the same as i want

---- sorry for my english --- i hope you understand me :-)

the html ---->

```
<div class="pagination"> 
<a href="#" class=""><span>1</span></a>
<a href="#" class=""><span>2</span></a>
</div>
<div class="togglemenu">sdfsdfsdfsdf</div>
```

the jquery ----> when the value in span is 1 - then hide tooglemenu .... but it doesn't work

```
$('.pagination').click(function () {
if ($('.pagination span').html() == 2) {
$(".togglemenu").hide();
}
});
```

can anyone help me ? i'm new the jquery-world :-)

Answer (score 2):

First, you want to have your click event handler on the actual span you are clicking on, rather than on the entire `pagination` block.

```
$('.pagination span').click(function() {
```

Second, your `if` condition should be testing the current span that was clicked on and not just the first `span` in your html.  By using `$(.pagination span).html()` you are only checking your very first `span` element which is `1`.  Within your event handler function, the `this` variable always points to the `span` that is currently being clicked on.

```
if ($(this).html() == 2) {
```